# Use jdom2.Document as argument to Response.ok().entity(...)

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Basically, I am looking forward to pass `jdom2.Document` object as to be parsed by `Entity` and sent back in resposne to client in XML or Json format as mentioned by the Accept / produce methods?

How could I convert `jdom2.Document` object to somethign valid for `Response.ok().entity(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate a `String` that contains the XML. JDOM provides [`XMLOutputter.outputString(org.jdom2.Document)`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html#outputString%28org.jdom2.Document%29) for this.

```
XMLOutputter outputter = ...;
String xml = outputter.outputString(document);
return Response.ok(xml).build();
```

Comment: That returns the XML in json accept as well. It doesn't convert it to json string

Comment: Yes. But a JDOM2 document is an XML document. Converting from XML to JSON is not trivial.

Comment: No, I believe if you return like JAXBContext then you don't need to manipulate json/xml output manually. It always convert it on its own isn't it. Same way I want to return that document in entity so that it can be converted to json or xml based on the annotation or media type defined.